# Rails js.erb append block link_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I need to append a `link_to block` in, but I encountered some troubles.

Here is the `link_to block`

```
<%=link_to user_create_question_sort_section_path, :remote=> true , :method=> :post do %>
    <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes"></button>
<% end %>
```

It works fine and displays perfectly in html, but it would display wrongly if I use `js.erb` to append.

In **js.erb** I typed

```
$('#sort_btn').append("<%= j link_to user_create_question_sort_section_path, :remote=> true , :method=> :post do %><button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes"></button><% end %>");
```

However, it displays like this

[image]

It seems took the `path` arg as name.

Comment: You need to just render the view instead of giving the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `link_to` block into a partial and render it in your `js.erb` template.

```
# _link.html.erb

<%= link_to user_create_question_sort_section_path, :remote=> true, :method=> :post do %>
  <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes"></button> 
<% end %>
```

And in your template, render the link

```
# action.js.erb

$('#sort_btn').append("<%= render 'link' %>");
```